# What is the difference between making android game with hand or some game engine?

Tags: android, game-engine

I want to know what is the difference between making game with game engine and code that you write yourself. in other words how the game engine help us to develop a game. 
and can introduce me some good game engines for android platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An engine is going to help you because it already has some basic functionalities, like: collision handling, sprites and so on! In other words you don't need to be concerned about coding in order to solve basic problems that every single game has in common!(you will write fewer lines of code) Look I'm not an expert in this subject but you can try: Cocos 2D and AndEngine, take a look at the links bellow:

http://cocos2d.org/

http://www.andengine.org/

I hope it will be usefull!

see you!